# What does %h and other symbols like it mean?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have seen `%` and then some letter for example `%h` in config files in Ubuntu and in other Linux distributions but I do not know the names of them or what they all do, so I am just wondering if there is a resource that lists them all and/or gives descriptions of what they all do? If am not mistaken I think that `%h` is a variable for a users home directory but I am not positive.

Comment: In what context? `%` as an escape character is used in several unrelated formats, it can mean completely different things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of %h in a config file should be documented in the corresponding program's man page. Here are some examples for `%h`:

- [smb.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/smb.conf) - the Internet hostname that Samba is running on.
- [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) - same as %b (locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan))
- [ssh_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) - various (e.g. remote host name)
- [sshd_config](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) - home directory of the user being authenticated

Comment: Here is a snippet from the sshd _config ChrootDirectory %h

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're thinking of `date` format strings?

`date '+%h'`, for example, returns the current month.

Run `man date` to see other sequences like this.